# What is the color logic behind big mobile application brands like facebook, google etc.?

Tags: design, mobile-application, color, google, facebook

Why is facebook blue? Why is whatsapp green, skype in skyblue, Gmail in Red? What is the color logic behind all these applications?

Comment: Some rumors say that Mark Zuckerberg is colorblind and thus cant see Red or Green

Comment: Yes and for most others I think it is most likely because of emotion: http://www.fastcompany.com/3009317/why-is-facebook-blue-the-science-behind-colors-in-marketing

Comment: I'd want this question reopened (I'm not the OP), this is not an opinion-based question, as there is a psychology in choosing colours to preceive certain meanings -- especially with logos and marketing, as well as colour decision for colour blindness, or different types of disabilities -- all these are VERY relevant to UX Discussions.

Comment: why is this on hold? While I agree this question's wording could be improved, this is not an "opinion based" question, there's quite some documentation to support the answers, even straight answers by those who did the logos!

Comment: @Devin, true, but that's really just citing *their* opinion then.

Comment: *their* opinion on how *they* designed those brands? there can't be anything more clear and direct than the reasons they choose to do the work, *by their own words*, talk about an authoritative opinion! I understand one thing is to ask a general rule that applies to ALL those brands, then the answer would be opinionated, because there's NOT a general rule (this is why I say the wording could be improved). It's a very different thing to ask *"John Doe did the X brand, why he choose to do it like so?"* and then have John Doe himself answering *"I did it this way because yadda yadda yadda"*

Comment: @DA01: So is anything with design, but with colour specifically, there is a lot of logic.  Red and orange is a warm tone, blue and green is a cool tone, these are solid facts.  10% of men have colourblindness, and using red and green, or at least, together, is a very bad idea because they wont' be able to differentiate it, this is solid facts.  There's not much opinion in the above.  There's list and list of psychological reasons to use specific colour that are backed by a century of academic research.  Branding, logo and Marketing especially make use of these facts

Comment: @Devin in that case, this question is way too broad. It should be split up asking why each of those individual brands chose the colors they did.

Comment: @Novina those are all 'solid facts' that are mostly arbitrary to the choosing of brand colors. Yes, there is psychological research on all of that, but it's really not used to the extent that many would think. More often than not, a color is chosen because 'it looks nice' and 'works with the design'.

Comment: IMHO the one with an opinion is you, the answers are well documented. Again, I agree with the format of the question should be improved, but your answer to @Novina is a bit too much. If there were a chance to answer this question, you would know that FB logo was created with several parameteres (including MZ's color blindness) , or that Google colors have a meaning, or Gmail and everything related to Google brands has extensive work behind. Or that all these companies have style manuals to handle branding (skype's has 100 pages!).... But well, the question can't be answered

Comment: @DA01 That's your opinion.  At my work, I have to deal with colours all the time, and colours are constantly rejected by product managers because it doesn't follow the WCAG standard... or it looks too similar to other colours to colour blind people, etc.  Good UX design should WORK for everyone, not just that "it looks nice".

Comment: @Novina *branding* colors really shouldn't be subject to WCAG standards other than make sure things like whatever color you go with adequately contrasts with whatever text color you go with and the like. I agree, *color in general* may very well--especially at the UI--be subject to these things, but we're talking branding here.

Answer (score 1):

## Most brands choose a specific color for branding and stick with it.

There is no general answer to why the specific color was chosen by what company. But in general, it seems to be a good idea for a brand to choose a color that is associated with it.

In general, choosing a brand color helps building brand recognition. As you correctly stated, the colors of big brands like Facebook are immediately associated with the brand itself. Having a clearly defined color scheme gives the user a way to recognize the brand instantly.

Why does brand A chose color B? That is basically a free choice of the brand. Usually, there is a lot of psychology considered when choosing a brand color. Blue, for example, has a calming effect, making the users of Facebook feel at home and welcome.

Another thing to consider is using a color that is not associated with any other relevant brand. So if, for example, Google had decided to brand Google+ with a similar blue to the Facebook blue, that would have the potential to confuse the user and negate the positive effects on brand recognition.

But ultimately, it is up to the company what color to choose for branding. There is no general guideline.